# $\lim_{n \to \infty} B_n=a_n*a_{n+1}$ when $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find a sequence $a_n$ so that $b_n=a_n*a_{n+1}$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=0$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\neq 0$

The latest idea is maybe to use log, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It can be shown that if $a_n$ is convergent and its limit is not $0$, then the limit of $b_n$ will also not be $0$.

However, $a_n$ can be divergent!

$$a_n = \begin{cases}\frac1n; & n\text{ is even}\\
1 & n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: but in the case of n even $lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$

Comment: @gbox So what? The limit of $a_n$ is not $0$, because the limit does not exist. Isn't that what you wanted? If you wanted something else, then edit your question.

Comment: you are right, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If one of the two terms in $b_n$ grows much slower that the other shrinks, you may have the property on $b$. You can choose for instance odd indices for the first ones, even indices for the even terms.

For $a$, it could be useful to have an infinite quantity of $a_k$ above a threshold. But also an infinity below, otherwise you would not respect the property on $b$ (as it would be bounded below by a not-zero term).

Let us try with $a_{2k}= \frac{1}{(k+1)^\alpha}$, $\alpha > 0$. It shrinks. The subsequence converges to 0. Now try, for the odd term,  $a_{2k+1}={(k+1)^\beta}$, $\beta \ge 0$. It is greater than $1$.
Thus, the sequence $a_k$ does not converge.

Now $b_k=(k+1)^{\beta-\alpha}$. If $\beta < \alpha$, you have a parametric starting point for an infinite number of similar formulas.

EDIT: an other answer is close to taking $\beta = 0$ and $\alpha =1$.

Answer (score 0):

If, as per assumption, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_na_{n+1})=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=(\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n)^2.
$$
It is thus impossible to satisfy all conditions.